# Using jquery to write information from other parts of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var printLinks = function () {
    var links  = $(.info).code;
    document.write(links);
};

</script>

<form>
<input type="button" value="printlinks" onclick="printLinks()"></input>
</input>
</form>
```

I am trying to write to a document all of the text in a certain element type that is a child of an element I query by class `$(.info)`. I know document.write is not the best method for writing to a document. info is the class of the parent element of the `<code>` tags that contain the links I want to print. I am very new to jQuery so I am probably misusing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid using document.write, use .text() or .html() operators of jQuery if you are using jQuery (as it seems you are)

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to do, can you be a bit clearer? You want to grab the child links of the element with 'info' as the class and print them elsewhere? is that correct?

Comment: can you put the rest of the code? i dont see one with a class of `.info`. what is `.info` exactly?

Comment: the rest of the code is the source code for http://embed.ly/providers. I just wanted to print out a list of all the providers with the info you get when you hover over them to a new document I need to copy paste a bunch of that info for a whitelist thats why I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I understand correctly, you want to grab the content in the element with the class `info`. If that is correct you want to take the following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printLinks() {
  var content = $('.info').html();     // Grab innerHTML of element

  $('#idOfTargetElement').html( content ); // write the content here
}
</script>
```

EDIT:

See this fiddle for clarification:

http://jsfiddle.net/XD5qj/

Comment: Be sure that you have a container element on your page that you can use to post the target data to: <div id="idOfTargetElement"></div>

Comment: Obviously this is scaled back, but you can adapt to your needs. jQuery provides a lot of tools at your disposal for DOM traversal and cloning elements and various bits of code. I would suggest reading through some of the jQuery API/documentation and some of the examples.

Comment: i have this javascript embedded right in my copied verson of the html of embed.ly/providers. how do i print all the info to a separate blank document to see? thanks

Comment: i will definitely spend some time going through the jquery api thanks

Comment: What do you mean a separate blank document? Like a popup window?

Comment: open another browser window that had nothing but that info on it. i have been going off the answer @kieran helped me with now

Comment: writing it to a div i create in the bottom of that window is fine though

Comment: using this code I only get the html from the last code element $(function() {
    
    $('.info code').each(function() {
        
       $('.output').html( $(this).html() ); 
        
    });
    
});
</script>

<div class="output"></div>

Comment: Thats because the `.html()` function replaces the existing code in the target container. You will need to use `.append()` or `.appendTo()` in order to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html() function of jQuery.

For example:

```
<script>
$(function(){

  var links = $('.info code').html();
  $('.output').html(links);


});
</script>

<div class="info"><code>Example code</code></div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

If you have multiple "< code>" tags, you want to use the handy "each()" function of jQuery:

```
$('.info code').each(function(){
  $('.output').append($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: will links just become an object that contains all of the html code that is in code tags with the parent element with a class of info? This code worked to print the first item with the class info but not all of them. there is a whole list of them i want to print out the info for. does this make sense?

Comment: all the info tags on <li> items in the same <ul>. can i find the length of that unordered list and run the a for loop that many times to print all of them instead of just the first?